# Bound target not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, target

I have bound two listbox controls to an xml file (i.e one list box bound to the xml and the other bound to the first listbox). The listboxes display node values within the xml file as a result of the binding. Add, Edit and Delete operations can be made and do persist to the source file, however the target doesn't get updated unless the window is closed and then reopened. The code for the first list box is as follows:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" Width="224" Height="115" Margin="0,0,0,5" 
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecipeList}, XPath=recipeType,
Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Black">
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Height="35" Background="#181818">
                           <TextBlock Background="Black" Margin="1" FontWeight="Bold" 
                           Padding="7" Height="33" Width="184" Foreground="#D0D0D0">
                                 <TextBlock.Text>
                                      <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}">
                                           <Binding XPath="@description" />
                                      </MultiBinding>
                                 </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                      </StackPanel>
                 </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and for the second listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox2" Width="218" Height="144" Margin="0,0,0,5"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}"
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel Height="auto" Background="#181818">
                    <TextBlock Padding="7">
                          <StackPanel Background="Black" Margin="-5.5,-5.5,-6,-6.8">
                                <TextBlock Width="210" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding XPath=name}"
                                Background="Black" Foreground="#D0D0D0" Padding="0"                 Margin="5,0,0,3" />
                                <TextBlock Width="187" FontSize="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Text="{Binding XPath=summary}" Background="Black" Foreground="Gray" 
                                Margin="5,0,0,5" />
                          </StackPanel>
                    </TextBlock>
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My question is how to update the target or refresh/reload the window in this case.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: By target, do you mean _listBox2_.

Answer (score 0):

In ListBox2, you are binding to a specific item (listBox1.SelectedItem) so IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem should be false. IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is for when you are binding to a collection but want only the selected item.

Comment: The listbox1 is bound to the data source which is the xml file and the listbox2 is bound to the listbox1 as an itemsource. Once operations are made, the xml file is updated and the bound controls should also be. The desired effect is that the bound controls are refreshed/reloaded thus listbox2 would be updated as listbox1 is. The value of listbox1 is static however that of listbox2 is not and this is inicative of the xml file and the xml elements displayed by these controls. See sample xml file:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<recipe xmnls="">
  <recipeList>
    <recipeType description="Breakfast">
      <recipeInfo>
        <name>Omelet on Toast</name>
        <summary>A great breakfast</summary>
        <ingredients>Two eggs, a loaf of bread, ..</ingredients>
        <instructions>Get the eggs and ...</instructions>
      </recipeInfo>
    </recipeType>
    <recipeType description="Lunch">
    </recipeType>
    <recipeType description="Dinner">
    </recipeType>
  </recipeList>
</recipe>